# Output from a thread created using pthread_create is not getting printed

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am learning threads & POSIX thread from *Modern Operating systems* by *Tanenbaum*. This is an example I am trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_hello(void *tid)
{
    printf("Hello..Greetings from thread %d\n",tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[10];
    int status,i=0;

//  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Creating thread %d\n",i);
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,print_hello,(void*)i);

        if(status != 0){
            printf("Oops pthread_create returned error code %d\n",status);
            exit(-1);
        }
//  }
    exit(0);
```

}

Output is:

```
Creating thread 0
```

Why does not it go to my `start_routine`, which is `print_hello` function here? What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `main()` thread doesn't wait for the thread to complete. So depending on the scheduling of the threads, you may or may not see the output from `print_hello` thread. When `main()` thread exits, the whole process dies.

Use [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) to wait for the created thread to complete or just exit only the main thread using [`pthread_exit(0);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) instead of `exit(0)`.